# Influence of "being" on the meaning of a sentence

Tags: sentence-meaning, infinitive-vs-gerund, passive-voice

> I look forward to being interviewed on the current affairs programme.

Is it a correct a sentence? If it is, who will take interview? I think, the subject of this given sentence, ***I***, will not take interview of others, rather someone will take his interview. Am I right? If I write the following sentences, can they be considered to be correct sentences?

> I look forward to being ***interviewing*** on the current affairs programme.

Or,

> I look forward to ***be*** being interviewed on the current affairs programme.

If they are correct, please tell me what are the differences among these three sentences?

The preposition ***to*** does not allow present participle form of verbs after it, but if *ing-form* of verbs is used as gerund, ***to*** can be followed by *ing-form* of verbs. Am I right? Is ***being interviewed*** a gerund? If ***being*** is not gerund, it couldn't be used after ***to***. If it is possible, please say details about this topic.

Comment: Only the first sentence is correct. It is passive, so we don't know who is doing the interview. However it is whoever this statement is directed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct. "Be interviewed" is the passive of "interview" so one can be interviewed, and can look forward to that.

> The preposition to does not allow present participle form of verbs after it, but if ing-form of verbs is used as gerund, to can be followed by ing-form of verbs

Indeed, "being" here is a gerund. "Look forward to" is a compound verb thatis most often followed by a gerund.

The other sentences are incorrect or dont have the meaning you probably want. "Being interviewing" seems meaningless to me. "*Being interviewing" mixes active and passive, and "be being" is double passive.